# Wifi not working on HP ENVY m6

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hardware

I've been doing a fresh 16.04 install on a laptop I borrowed.
Wifi is not working and I've run the wireless-info script I found on this website.
Here's the link to the pastebin :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23813395/

I hope anyone can help me since I've found myself not able to fix it.

Thanks & Peace,
J

Comment: It is hard blocked. Check BIOS or a hardware switch. Try Fn+F12 keys.

Comment: my bad, wrong results posted, I managed to unsoft block with the wifi switch but it stays hard blocked.
here are the updated results http://paste.ubuntu.com/23813395/

Comment: Try to reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: You can also try to run `sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: I did, then computer won't boot anymore because of UEFI boot, turned back legacy boot. It worked, but wifi still won't turn on. Trying the modprobe thing now. Thanks for your help.   

EDIT: tried `sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all`  
it had no effect.